# TextField component with type=date creates unwanted calendar icon

Tags: material-ui, react-typescript

The `<TextField>` component provided by material-ui for some reason generates a small icon at the end of the input depending on the `type` of the TextField.

If `type="date"` then I get this icon at the end of the input:

[image]

If `type="time"` then I get a clock icon.
What is confusing is that these icons doesn't show on all of the systems I am testing on. For example, the vm I am using do not display these icons, same goes for my ios device. But when I try it out locally these icons shows up.

I have read the [documentation](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/) for TextFields but I can't find any api references for these icons.
First I thought that it was some kind of `endAdornment`, but trying to override the icon with an `endAdornment` only causes the component to generate additional icons/strings.

This is my `<TextField>` component:

```
<TextField
    onChange={this.OnChange.bind(this)}
    name="date"
    value={this.state.date}
    label={GetText(Text.Date)} 
    variant="filled"
    type="date"
    InputProps={{
        disableUnderline: true,
        style: {
            backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
            borderRadius: "4px",
            border: "1px solid #CED4DC",
            fontSize: ".81em",
        }
    }}
    InputLabelProps={{
        shrink: true
    }}
/>
```

If anyone knows a way to remove these icons, I am all ears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

...after having removed every class from the element without success I realised the icon was related to html and so I discovered that the icon is just a re-skin of the standard "down-arrow" provided in a date input type.

Using this css removes the icon:

```
input[type="time"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
display: none;
-webkit-appearance: none;}
```

but of course that also removes the "drop-down" of dates.

Sometimes it is not easy being dumb...

Comment: Can you please provide an example how to implement this

Comment: @zwebie well, you literally only need to copy the provided code and place it in your style.css, or other css file. The css provided will affect all inputs with the type 'time'.

Answer (score 1):

For people using material-ui

for the root of the css class of the input

```
classes={{root: classes.InputRoot}}
```

styles

```
InputRoot: {
'&::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator': {
      display: 'none',
      '-webkit-appearance': 'none'
    }
}
```